# Китайская теорема об остатках Python

Tags: python, классы, biginteger, класс

Нужно реализовать программу для решения системы линейных уравнений в Zn (с помощью китайской теоремы об остатках). Используя класс BigInteger.

Но я не понимаю как это реализовать на питоне, на сколько я знаю BigInteger в питоне не нужен, и китайская теорема никак не поддаётся понимаю.
Прошу помочь с моим заданием.

Comment: Нужно больше подробностей. Поставьте задачу. Китайская теорема имеет много применений. Что конкретно нужно вам?

Answer (score 1):

ну так откройте википедию (https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%BE%D0%B1_%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%85)

там есть "Алгоритм на основе китайской теоремы об остатках"

1. вычислим `M = prod(a_i)`

   ```
    math.prod(a_data)
   ```

где `a_data` - список коэффициентов а_i

в питоне действительно не нужно BigIngeger для этого, питон и так с целыми работает как с числами неограниченной (условно) длины

2. вычисляем `M_i = 1 / M_i`

и т.д.

по сути задача же в несколько строчек будет

Comment: Обратный вычислить не так легко. Делением вы не отделаетесь. Нужен расширенный алгоритм Евклида или функция [pow](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#pow) которая начиная с Питона 3.8 умеет вычислять обратный по модулю.

Comment: ну да, это я скопировал текст из алгоритма, там же (по ссылке) указано, что можно использовать расширенный алгоритм Евклида